# What is the simplest way to data bound radio button list in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime

First of all I'm new to WPF, I'm using MVVM Light Toolkit and for about 2 days now I'm scraping the internet trying to find a easy way to create a radio button list. I found many examples that were either too complex in my opinion, either "hacks" ish to some old bug or even non working examples.

Let's say that in your code-behind you have this list of strings

```
List<string> options = new List<string>();

        options.Add("option 1");
        options.Add("option 2");
        options.Add("option 3");
        options.Add("option 4");
```

So I want to ask you, what is the simplest way to create a radio button list with `options`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the easiest one is:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Options}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton Content="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

where `Options` is a property of your data context, like this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Options
{
    get { return options; }
}
```

But I think, that you'll want to get selection result back.
So, the task becomes more complex. You need view model:

```
public class OptionViewModel
{
    public bool? IsChecked { get; set; }
    public string OptionName { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you must convert list of string to the list of view models:

```
public IEnumerable<OptionViewModel> Options
{
    get { return optionsAsViewModels ?? (optionsAsViewModels = new List(options.Select(_ => new OptionViewModel { OptionName = _ }))); }
}
private IEnumerable<OptionViewModel> optionsAsViewModels;
```

and make some changes into item template:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Options}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton Content="{Binding OptionName}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

try below sample of code :-

```
 <DataTemplate>
               <RadioButton GroupName="Test"
                            Content="{Binding ItemDescription}"
                            IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                            Margin="5,1"/>
           </DataTemplate>
```

and in server side :-

```
public ViewModel()
        {
            Test = new Collection<SelectableItem>
                {
                    new SelectableItem { ItemDescription = "Option 1"},
                    new SelectableItem { ItemDescription = "Option 2"},
                    new SelectableItem { ItemDescription = "Option 3", IsSelected = true},
                    new SelectableItem { ItemDescription = "Option 4"}
                };
        }
```

and

```
public class SelectableItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string ItemDescription { get; set; }

        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    }
```